# Angular (Paginated API Request) You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, api, get, request

I'm trying to make a Multiple API Request and merge all the results in a single array, but my problem is that one of the API has a paginated response
Each time that I try to subscribe to the Observable i get the following error

"You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.multipleDataRequest().subscribe(responseList => {
      console.log(responseList);
    // this.response1 = responseList[0];
    // this.response2 = responseList[1];
    // return this.arr = this.response1.concat(this.response2);
    });
 }
```

service.ts

```
fetch(url) {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      mergeMap(
      data => {
        const page = data['next_page'];
        console.log(page);
        if (page !== null) {
          return this.fetch(page);
        }
      }
      )
    );
  }

    multipleDataRequest(): Observable<any[]> {
    // const news = this.http
    // .get<INews[]>('xxx');
    const articles = this.fetch('https://casounico.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/es/articles.json?');
    // return forkJoin([news, articles]);
    return forkJoin([articles]);
```

I'm sharing a StackBlitz as well https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7j5v1z

Thank you all, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mergeMap takes a function that would return a stream.
but when page is null the function returns undefined, thus the error.
To eliminate the error, simply:

```
data => {
        const page = data['next_page'];
        console.log(page);
        if (page !== null) {
          return this.fetch(page);
        } else return [];  // return whatever you want, but it needs to be an array, observable or promise. 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

mergeMap takes a function that would return a stream. but when page is null the function returns undefined, thus the error. To eliminate the error, simply:

```
data => {
        const page = data['next_page'];
        console.log(page);
        if (page !== null) {
          return this.fetch(page);
        } else return empty();  // return whatever you want, but it needs to be an array, observable or promise. 
      }
```